# R ggplot geom_bar: Change transparency inside bars, keeping contour/boundary the same

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

## Problem Statement

Is there a way of changing the transparency of the inside of the bars in a `geom_bar` barplot in `ggplot2`? Basically I would like to make the "fill" be more transparent than the "color".

## Minimal Working Example

```
# Create fake data
df <- data.frame(language=c("Python", "Python", "R", "Julia", "R"), 
                 filetype=c("Script", "Notebook", "Notebook", "Script", "Script"), 
                 count=c(3,10,4,2,1))
# Make a barplot with ggplot
ggplot(data=df) +
 geom_bar(aes(x=filetype, y=count, fill=language), position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

I tried using `alpha` outside of `aes()` but it just makes everything transparent. Bonus points if you can also make this transparency change appear in the legend!

## Solution

I think I might have found a solution. The trick is to add `color=language` in the `aes()`. I think this effectively separates the filling color from the contour color. In this way, when we set `alpha` value inside `geom_bar` we get the desired effect. Here is the complete example

```
# Create fake data
df <- data.frame(language=c("Python", "Python", "R", "Julia", "R"), 
                 filetype=c("Script", "Notebook", "Notebook", "Script", "Script"), 
                 count=c(3,10,4,2,1))
# Make a barplot with ggplot
ggplot(data=df) +
 geom_bar(aes(x=filetype, y=count, fill=language, color=language), 
          position="dodge", stat="identity", alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is <del>to add another layer.</del>

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = filetype, y = count, fill = language, color = language)) +
  geom_col(
    position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"),
    alpha = 0.1
  ) +
#  geom_col(
#    position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"),
#    fill = NA
#  ) +
NULL
```

Result

[image]

---

I added two more bonus points:

1) `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(... stat="identity")`

2) `position_dodge(preserve = "single")` to keep bar width consistent across groups

---

**EDIT**

If we want less code, black borders, transparent `fill`, and keep bar aligned in the center we can use

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = filetype, y = count, fill = language)) +
  geom_col(
    position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"),
    alpha = 0.1,
    color = "black"
  )
```

Output

[image]